# Referenced DLL in Referenced .NET C# Project not releasing memory when form closed

Tags: .net, memory-leaks, dispose

I am using the demo version of an sdk (just a compiled dll) to have a webcam read barcodes in a windows app.

I cannot get it to release any memory when I'm done with the form.  While the form is open it will continue to use up more memory until closed.  It will not release any memory when closed.  When I open the same form again, it starts gobbling up more memory until closed.  This process continues until there is no more available memory and then the main app crashes.

There is obviously a problem with the barcode.dll not releasing resources. However, shouldn't I be able to kill my referenced project and that offending dll to get it to release whatever memory it won't give up?

I've tried:

1. Calling gc.Collect directly
2. Removing all events on closing form
3. Manually disposing of timer and barcodescanning objs

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or give me any ideas? I hope I posted enough info.

Here's the code:

originalForm.vb (in main project)

```
Dim frm As New Library.Helpers.frmWebcamScanner(True)
If (frm.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then txtVIN.Text = frm.BarcodeReading
frm.Dispose()
```

Then I added this after frm.Dispose() line:

```
GC.Collect()
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
GC.Collect()
```

secondForm.cs (in referenced project)

```
namespace Library.Helpers
{
public partial class frmWebcamScanner : Form
{
    private bool _ScanningForVIN = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// The results of the scan
    /// </summary>
    public string BarcodeReading = "";

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ScanningForVIN">Are you trying to read a VIN? t/f</param>
    public frmWebcamScanner(bool ScanningForVIN)
    {
        _ScanningForVIN = ScanningForVIN;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmWebcamScanner_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Top = this.Top + 10;
        barcodeReader1.Start();
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void barcodeReader1_BarcodeReady(object sender, BarcodeEvent e)
    {
        BarcodeReading = e.barcode.barcode;
        if (_ScanningForVIN)
        {
            //Remove the leading *I if there:
            BarcodeReading = BarcodeReading.Replace("*I", "");
            //Remove all asterisks:
            BarcodeReading = BarcodeReading.Replace("*", "");
        }
        this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
        PrepAndClose();
    }

    private void frmWebcamScanner_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        {
            this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
            PrepAndClose();
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Abort;
        PrepAndClose();
    }

    private void PrepAndClose()
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        barcodeReader1.Stop();
        this.Close();
    }       
}
}
```

Then I customized the designer.cs dispose code trying to free up everything to get the garbage collector to kick in.  I set a break point in here and verified everything went ok.

From the designer.cs:

```
/// <summary>
/// Clean up any resources being used.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && (components != null))
    {

        barcodeReader1.Stop();
        timer1.Stop();

        this.Load -= this.frmWebcamScanner_Load;
        this.KeyDown -= this.frmWebcamScanner_KeyDown;
        this.barcodeReader1.BarcodeReady -= this.barcodeReader1_BarcodeReady;
        this.timer1.Tick -= this.timer1_Tick;

        barcodeReader1.Dispose();
        barcodeReader1 = null;

        components.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Comment: Good thing you evaluated the demo, now you know that it is junk.  There is no fix for native components that leak memory.  Running them in a separate process so you can Kill() it when it gets out of hand is not something you should have to put up with.  Contact the vendor for support if you want to pursue this anyway.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I'm going to dump it!